# Choice of input values for a PS function.

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a function that accepts a range of input values. Most of the times, users pick one of the 3 values (Value1, Value2, Value3). Occasionally, he might input a value not in the set (value 5).  Though, I want to provide the user with a choice, to avoid typos etc, I don’t want to restrict them to only 3 values. I use the following code, which doesn’t serve the purpose. Any suggestions?

```
function get-Something(){
param([ValidateSet('Value1','Value2','Value3')] [String] $yourChoice)
return $yourChoice 
}
```

Comment: Well, you can't have it both ways... Either you allow a free input (which you can later validate) or you provide the options for input. I'm not really sure what are you asking for...

Comment: Thank you arco444. If I don't find a solution, i might have to go for FREE INPUT, and validate it in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option might be to have 4 parameter sets, with Value1, Value2, and Value3 being switch parameters used to select one of the 3 common values, and Value being a string parameter used to specify an arbitrary value, each within it's own parameter set so that they're mutually exclusive.

Comment: mjolinor, Thank you for your inputs. If we follow your suggestion, how are we going to avoid, a user picking both inputs? (Value1 or Value2) and Value3.

Comment: That's the point of having them in separate parameter sets.  Once you choose one, that dictates the parameter set that's being used. The others are no longer valid (because they're in a different parameter set), and Powershell will not let you use them.